# Difficulty understanding Sums - Number Theory

Tags: summation

I've been trying to understand the following equality for quite some time. And since I bump into it frequently I cannot oversee it:

$$\underset{d|n}\sum d=\underset{d|n}\sum \displaystyle\frac{n}{d}$$

Am I overlooking something here that is so obvious that the teacher doesn't even say the proof in class, just mentioning it? I just can't see the proof.

Comment: Did your process of trying to understand it include checking some concrete examples?

Comment: Yes, of course, I checked with six for example, and I can see that it's equal alright. I see that those divisions give you one divisor of n. But, then what? I'm stuck, maybe it's that I am up all night :P I don't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change of variables.  Whenever $d|n$, then $c=\frac{n}{d}$ divides $n$ as well (in fact, $cd=n$).  Since each $d$ corresponds to a $c$ and vice versa, $$\sum_{d|n}d=\sum_{c|n}\frac{n}{c}.$$